# How to echo message if source is up to date

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to display a message in some Turkic languages if source program is up to date.

```
all: compile program message

compile: hello.cc

hello: hello.cc
    g++ hello.cc -o hello

program: hello

message:
    @echo Selam! Ne var ne yok?
    @echo Selam! Hər şey yaxşıdır. Sizdə nə var, nə yox?

.PHONY: program compile
```

This is my makefile. When source code is up to date it displays message

```
Selam! Ne var ne yok?
Selam! Hər şey yaxşıdır. Sizdə nə var, nə yox?
```

But when the source code changes it displays again "Selam .."

```
make
g++ hello.cc -o hello
Selam! Ne var ne yok?
Selam! Hər şey yaxşıdır. Sizdə nə var, nə yox?
```

Is there a way to prevent this.

If you don't know the answer please don't post unnecessary comments.

I'm a programmer, I do know how to change locale settings. I would like to understand this subject or concept thoroughly.

Comment: What's wrong with the default message of `make: 'hello' is up to date.`?

Comment: It is in English but I'd like to display message in Turkish.

Comment: Make already has a [Turkish](http://translationproject.org/PO-files/tr/make-4.2.1.tr.po) translation, you just need to set the system locale.

Comment: I do know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-q` command line switch to check if given targets are already up to date. To do this, you'll want to move the `message` first in the `all:` list, so that the check happens before the other targets are made.

Example:

```
all: message compile program

...

message:
    @make -q compile program && echo Everything up to date! || true
```